# check is valid my string in custom format? the number of brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex for check this format:

[some digits][some digits][some digits][some digits][some digits][some digits]**#**

"some digits" means each number (0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or .... ), 2 digits, 3 digits, or more...

but it's important that each open bracket be closed before another open one...

actually I want to check the format and also get the number of [].
I tried this code for getting number of [] :

`Regex.Matches( input,  "[]" ).Count`

but it didnt work.

thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the regex you're looking for:

```
^(\[\d+\])+#$
```

See [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/66).

**Sample Code for the Count**

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"^(\[\d+\])+#$");
string bracketCount = myRegex.Match(yourString).Groups[1].Count;
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(` starts capture Group 1
- `\[`opens a bracket
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `\]` matches the closing bracket
- `)` closes Group 1
- `+` matches this 1 or more times
- `#` the hash
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: thanks for your reply, I want to know the number of [] also. how can I get it?

Comment: and also I want to check end of string with #

Comment: Good edit, the previous version was incorrect because it would have matched `[aaa][[aaa]`.

Comment: FIY, Added demo, explanation and code for the count—let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: @zx81 thanks for your perfect answer  :) I edited my question, actually I want to be just digits between brackets, can u edit your answer?

Comment: Just edited the answer, let me know if that's what you want. :)

Comment: By the way for the count it is easy because of C#'s awesome Capture Collections, would be more complicated in a different engine. :)